# Hidden until triggered(Indesign CS6 Folio Builder, DPS Content) not working in adobe content viewer on ipad

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm having a problem with adobe indesign folio builder when I try to trigger a button to become viewable.
So, I have a multistate object(3 states), on first state(let's say home) I have 2 buttons that go to 2 other states(some sort of pop-ups) and these other 2 states have a close button that I want to be "vissible" after the state that contains it is opened(reached).
The open popup from home state has 2 functions: 1.open popup state and 2.view close popup button.
The close button from popup states is set to "Hidden until triggered" and it has 2 functions attached: 1.got to state 1(home) and 2.hide the close button(hide itself).
The sistem seems to be correct because it works when I view it in SWF preview (emulator) but when I try it on the ipad in Adobe Content Viewer I doesn't work like it should(the close state button remain active all the time whether it's triggered or not).
Any ideas??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this feature works only on Interactive PDF